How to export data with specific column value from phpmydmin
I have a huge database of 2M rows of data in localhost phpmyadmin. Data is about different countries. I want to export data related to USA from column named country (about 400k). But with the options available in phpmyadmin I can not do it. it either exports all data which is near 1.5gb (which cannot be imported into my online shared server) or just 500 rows with select and export option. Is there a way to export it country wise?
It would be good if exported data is in a format where 1 insert has 5000 rows in it.
So how can I export data that I have in
`SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `country` LIKE 'United States'`

This options exports all data.

This option exports only 500 selected data or second one exports all data.


I don't know which version of phpMyAdmin (I'm on 5.2.1) you're using but I could do it with the following steps:
Just select "Export" after running the query. It doesn't matter how many rows I made it show here whether it's 25 or 500.

That got me to the following page. In my case, I tried it with query on a table called "items" having 6609 rows as its result. Selecting "Export" gives me the exported data I want.

Related: How to export data from multiple tables in phpmyadmin
